# How to reset the multi-picklist field values in a VF Page after clicking on browsers back button

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have developed a VF Page where i have used the multi-picklist field "Executed_Reporting__c"of a salesforce which have yes,no and not available as values in it.I am generating pdf or xls report.

When i go back from generated pdf or xls page to the Vf page where i provide input.If i again select the values of executed field the previous values which i selected is also getting added.I tried using cache="false" but its not helping.
Please help.

Below is the vf page code

```
<apex:page sidebar="true" showHeader="true"   controller="WeeklyTrackingCriteria">
 <script>
    function setFocusOnLoad() {}    
 </script>
 <apex:form > 
  <apex:pageBlock title="Activities">
   <apex:pageBlockSection title=" Weekly Legal Tracking" columns="2" >

    <apex:inputField label="Executed" value="{!ActivityObj.Executed_Reporting__c}"/>
   <apex:selectOption itemValue="PDF" itemLabel="PDF"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="XLS" itemLabel="XLS"/>
    </apex:selectList>
   </apex:pageBlockSection>

 <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
    <apex:commandButton value="Run Report" action="{!viewReport}"/> 
 </apex:pageBlockButtons>
 </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Why would a multi select field have values yes - no - not available?  These sound mutually exclusive to me and a simple picklist would suffice.

Comment: Hi crop1645,in the requirement the user wants to select combination of yes,no and not available so i have used multi-select picklist field.

Comment: requirement makes no sense but I'll defer to you and your business user. Akin to "Billy, it's Mom, are you  going to school today?" and Billy can answer : [Yes & No]  or [Yes and 'I reserve the right to not answer']

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to set the value back in the controller while executing the `viewReport()` method. I assume both pages are using the same controller? If so, the selected value remains in controller even if you redirect user to another page with the same controller (besides the case where you are using `setRedirect(true)` which will clear the view state and set your values back as well).

Comment: Hi mastor,in the controller after pageRef.setRedirect(false);....before returning the pageref what i need to set so that when i go back the previous values wont get added in the multipicklist....please help.

Comment: @Learner_sfdc You can either do `pageRef.setRedirect(true);` to clear the view state (and ALL previously set variables values), or just set back variable you wish manually (eg. `ActivityObj.Executed_Reporting__c = null;`)

Comment: @mastor can't i refresh the whole page when i click on browser's back button?

Comment: @Learner_sfdc You can for sure, using `pageRef.setRedirect(true);`. Otherwise all values remain in controller cache (view state). You have to clear it.

Comment: @mastor even if i make pageRef.setRedirect(true) when i go back the values which user provides remain same.The refresh is not happening.